# Сравнение пользовательского ввода с переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня такая вот проблема:

```
#coding:utf-8
import random
a = random.randint(0,5)
b = random.randint(0,5)
c = a + b
print(c)
d = input('Ответ:')
if (c == d):
    print('Да')
else:
    print('Нет')
```

Программа складывает 2 рандомных числа и сравнивает результат с пользовательским вводом. Но, когда я ввожу правильный ответ,программа выводит мне 'Нет'.Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Функция input всегда возвращает строку. Нужно результат привести к целому числу с помощью функции int.

Comment: Я плохо знаком с питоном. Но возможно поможет, если вы переведете d в число

Answer (score 2):

```
d = input('Ответ:')
```

Ввод сохраняется в формате str, а сравниваете вы с int.
Вам нужно переписать эту строку как преобразование строки в число:

```
d = int(input('Ответ:'))
```

И все заработает.

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. input() возвращает строковое значение, его нужно приводить к нужному типу данных, в данном случае int. Поэтому будет:

```
d = int(input('Ответ:'))
```